# java fx set scene from a different thread not working

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, callable

I am building a game and in my main application thread I have all my GUI related code running then for the managing of the actual game i have in a different thread as to avoid locking the GUI thread. I run the code for the game as a callable so i can return the winner to the GUI. Within the game thread I need to use the set scene method to change the scene but nothing happens and I am unsure why. When the game is started the GUI will prompt a player to start a new game then a gameManager thread will be made and it will be ran in a different thread. Here is an example of the source code:

```
gui.getStage(scene)
```

I would really appreciate some advice for this. I have checked all the threads start properly and i can print the getStage and i can print the scene so the objects are there.

Comment: You can't change the scene (or modify the UI in any way) from a background thread. [Schedule that to run on the FX Application Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-). I'm surprised you don't get an exception when you try to do this; are you squashing exceptions?

Comment: @James_D The first time I ran this i got an IncompatibleClassChangeError but i havent been able to recreate it since. I am not squashing Exceptions.

Comment: @James_D If i use run later wont it just lock up the main thread?

Comment: No; not unless you do something long-running on the FX Application Thread. Just do the UI updates (which should not take much time) on the FX Application Thread.You should create a [MCVE] and post it in your question.

Comment: @James_D will work on an example an update, the back end of the game involves locking in a while loop until a button is pressed, so i assume this is not ok for run later, or would it be ok? I know it is best to have event listeners and respond to button presses rather than wait for a button to be pressed but my brief specifies i do it this way :/

Comment: You really shouldn't need to do it that way at all. Pressing a button generates an event; there's no point in a thread sitting around doing nothing, only to do something when the button is pressed. Just do what needs to be done (including starting a new thread if needed) in the event handler for the button.

Comment: @James_D the thread only sits around for a short while, and i wouldnt normally do this but i need to as i have been told to, I have just tried using run later and it locks the main thread. Is there no work around for this?

Comment: You can't block the FX Application thread. If you really have to do it this way, you **must** do the blocking on the background thread, and then when you unblock the UI updates **must** happen on the FX Application thread via `Platform.runLater()`. Even if you're comfortable blocking the FX application thread for a short while (which you shouldn't be), any notifications for button presses happen on the FX Application thread, so they can't happen while the thread is blocked and you end up deadlocked.